# Using WebSecurity with NHibernate and Postgresql?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

Since I want to use Postgresql and NHibernate in my ASP.NET MVC4 project, I am wondering if it is possible to use the WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity for security and authentication features? NHibernate and Postgres are working already together, but when I want to set up the WebSecurity class with:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

I get the following error message:

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.
```

Creating a DbProviderFactory doesn't also work:

```
<system.data>
  <DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="Npgsql - .Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" invariant="Npgsql"
      description=".Net Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory" />
  </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Is it in principle possible to use the WebSecurity class without using EntityFramework? Or do you have any suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: I think default connection must be a ms sql server but not sure found a link that might help on this. http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Install this package http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core and try again.